# How to convert binary to hex code digit-wise

Tags: c++, binary, hex

In C++ I've four binary numbers stored in four `strings`, let's say:
`string s1="1010", s2="1011", s3="0100", s4="0011";` OR directly stored as `int`s: `int i1=10, i2=11, i3=4, i4=3;`.

I don't know which situation will lead to the better solution, that's why I wanted to clarify, that I can start with both.

Now what I want to do is as follows. Convert the above values to hex values and store them digit wise in one string: `string hex_result="AB43";` (as `1010=10=A`, `1011=11=B`, `0100=4=4`, `0011=3=3`). After that I need the actual value that `hex_result` describes, this is: `int value = 43843;` (as `AB43=43843`).

I know I can achieve that by evaluating the binary values directly as one string `"1010101101000011"`, but I need to have the hex code from the single binary strings, hence as described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @Amit's response, this will work as well:

```
int i1=10, i2=11, i3=4, i4=3;
char result[5];
sprintf(result,"%x%x%x%x\n", i1,i2,i3,i4);
```

This eliminates the bit shifting but produces the same result because of the nature of binary to hex conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with `int`'s:

```
int i1=10, i2=11, i3=4, i4=3;
int value = (i1<<12) + (i2<<8) + (i3<<4) + i4;
char hex_result[5];
sprintf(hex_result, "%X", value);
```

Should work...